# Optimizar cargue de paginas MVC 5

Tags: javascript, mvc, rendimiento

Cordial saludo, como se puede optimizar para que los archivos de javascript como jquery y otras librerias comunes a toda la solucion para que no se recarguen cada vez que se navega entre vistas?.

Como se puede observar en la imagen, los tiempos de descagar del navegador son muy altos, y si se hiciera una sola vez, está bien, pero esto se repite cada vez que se navega entre paginas

Estoy trabajando con MVC 5, en el BundleConfig tengo el BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; y la referencia al javascript está en el _Layout.

[image: Imagen de Cargue]

En el BundleConfig tengo referenciado las librerias que uso, las cuales se encuetran estaticas

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knd").Include(
      "~/js/kendo.all.min.js",
      "~/js/messages/kendo.messages.es-CO.min.js",
      "~/js/cultures/kendo.culture.es-CO.min.js"));
```

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

Gracias por la orientación

Comment: Tienes un directorio de estáticos desde donde se sirven los javascripts? Están separados los scripts de terceros como jQuery o los sirves en un bundle junto con tu aplicación? Qué webserver sirve los estáticos?

Comment: Revisa bien porque cuando se usa las developer tools, hay opciones que evitan el caché y por lo tanto, siempre se va a cargar de nuevo en cada F5.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tenia era que los archivos javascript no estaban quedando en caché haciendo que se descargaran cada vez que se cambiaba de controlador, para ello lo resolví de la siguiente manera (si alguno conoce alguna otra bienvenido).

en el archivo **Global.asax**

Modifiqué el:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Por

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
```

El cual permite habilitar o deshabilitar y permite agregar otras opciones.

Tambien deshabilité:

```
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Con esto pude resolver el problema y se mejoró notoriamente el tiempo de respuesta o rendimiento de la aplicación.